# VSCode for Java on FreeBSD

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, freebsd

After installing the Java Extension Pack, Spring Boot Extension Pack, and Lombok, I created a basic Spring Boot project just to test out VSCode (I followed the Spring Boot initializer which works surprisingly well).

I attempted to run the application (barebones / skeleton project) and when clicking on the "Play" button and selecting "Run Java", the Run dialog hangs indefinitely.

I can run the project from the command line, using maven to compile it followed by java -jar; however, I want to be able to do everything in VSCode including running and debugging.

I clicked on "check details", but there isn't any information for me to go by and make an educated guess as to what is going on.

EDIT:

Just to be clear, I am running VSCode on FreeBSD (which is not Linux).

Comment: I suspect this requires a bit more digging to get working on FreeBSD, until them, I'm using Intellij.

Answer (score 0):

you can have a look on this extension whitch look like Boot Dashboard in Eclipse and it enable you to manage your application and have a control above it andu can run multiple projects using it [in this Link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-spring-boot-dashboard#:%7E:text=Spring%20Boot%20Dashboard%20is%20a,debug%20a%20Spring%20Boot%20project.).

Note: i think it need java 11 to work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a description of how to use springboot. You can refer to it to see if there is a problem with any operation.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-spring-boot